# RealmChangeListener not being called on loading stored items from database

Tags: android, realm

I'm fetching some data from realm database and then applying more filters on `RealmResults` asynchronously. I've registered callback `RealmChangeListener` against each query but callback is not being triggered.

Below is the snippet:

```
RealmResults<Tweet> tweetsResults = RealmController
            .getInstance()
            .getRealm()
            .where(Tweet.class)
            .isNotNull("entities")
            .equalTo("entities.hashtags.text", inputString, Case.INSENSITIVE)
            .findAll();
```

I'm getting data in `tweetsResults` then I'm using `RealmResult` (not the Realm object) to get filtered data.

```
final RealmResults<Tweet> retweets = tweetsResults
            .where()
            .greaterThan("retweet_count", 0)
            .findAllSortedAsync("retweet_count", Sort.DESCENDING);

    retweets.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Tweet>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Tweet> element) {
            Toaster.shortToast("Found " + retweets.size()); // => Not triggered
        }
    });
```

Now using `findAllSortedAsync` I'm not getting any results (but results exist) and the callback is not being triggered.

When I change the second query to `findAllSorted` it starts giving me results.

Can you please guide me if my approach is not right.

I'm using **Realm v3.1.3** and Android Studio **2.3.2**

Comment: You need to store the `RealmResults` as a field reference and not just as a local reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given enough context so that I can tell what you are doing.  If, however, `retweets` is a local variable in a method, then @EpicPandaForce is (of course) exactly correct.

Think about it for a second.  As soon as the method exits, `retweets` goes out of scope.  That means that the `RealmResults` to which it referred is eligible for garbage collection.

Once it is gone, what would you expect the notifier to do?  The object on which you registered it as a notifier, is long gone!

In fact, because `retweets` is eligible for GC, so is the change listener.  They are both gone and you get no notifications

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. It worked for me. 

Can you please guide me how can I make distinct query Asynchronous, without using my own custom `AsyncTask` or `Runnable`. Like
myResults.where().distinct("source") I cannot use `findAllAsync` after distinct.

Comment: Yes... but not in the comments section of another question!  Just ask!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I found that it can be done by `distinctAsync()` :)

Comment: Yep!  There you go! Bam!  ;-)

Comment: @NaumanZubair Please accept the answer so that the community knows it is correct.